# When will the data in io.bytesIO() be lost?

Tags: python, django, io

I am a python beginner. At what point is the data in io.bytesio() erased?　Are you able to erase with this code?　　I want to save RAM and have higher performance.
This is my code, using Django.　The code creates a thumbnail after detecting the PDF upload.

```
def file_to_thumbnail(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        thumbnail_name= instance.file_name()+'_thumbnail.jpeg'
        thumbnail_obj =Thumbnail(file=instance)
        make_thumbnail = convert_from_path(instance.file.path, dpi=150, first_page=1, last_page=1, fmt='jpeg')
        buffer = io.BytesIO()
        make_thumbnail[0].save(fp=buffer, format='JPEG')
        thumbnail_obj.thumbnail.save(name=thumbnail_name,content=buffer)
        buffer.close()
```

I want to save RAM and have higher performance.　Does this code delete the io.bytesIO() data in RAM?

Comment: This is a Python object, if the object is garbage collected, it will release its data.

Comment: That being said, Python uses *lots* of memory, and is not meant to get the latest out of a CPU either. The idea of Python is that programmer's time is more expensive than processing time: saving a few bytes is usually not worth the effort: it often costs more to pay a programmer's salary than add an extra machine.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem
 Thanks for the fast reply.I had heard of gc but did not know much about it. I will try to study up on that as well.